# Quartz Compositor and other window managers of macOS

Tags: macos, window-manager

I've never in my life touched macOS, but I'm writing a work about operating systems, so I need to say something about macOS too.

[Wikipedia says that Quartz Compositor is the window manager of macOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartz_Compositor). But there are other window managers for macOS, like [Magnet](http://magnet.crowdcafe.com/) and [Spectacle](https://www.spectacleapp.com/).

I watched both Spectacle and Magnet in action on YouTube and they don't seem to me essentialy different than Quartz Compositor.

So I would like to know is the Quartz Compositor integrated in macOS like [DWM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_Window_Manager) is integrated in Windows and Magnet and Spectacle are slight extensions/modifications, or is it truly another window manager, like on Linux are xfwm4, i3, dwm, evilwm, openbox, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But there are other window managers for macOS, like Magnet and Spectacle.

Magnet and Spectacle aren't "window managers" in the sense you're thinking of. They're desktop applications which have features to automatically move and resize windows. They do not replace any component of the operating system.

> So I would like to know is the Quartz Compositor integrated in macOS like DWM is integrated in Windows

Correct. Quartz Compositor is not a user-replaceable component.